# Build matrix without loops?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy, matrix

I am trying to avoid using loops in the following code because it is slow. I am starting with a list of **labels** and a list of **metrics**, with the same length of a few million. I then want to make a symmetric NxN matrix where N is the number of unique label values (about 100). The matrix contains a comparison of the metric. Specifically, the metric is a list of lists and I want to count the number of matching elements in the sublist and update the output matrix with that value. The current code is:

```
matrix = {}
for i,value_i in enumerate(labels):
    for j,value_j in enumerate(labels):
        if i >= j:       
            matrix[(value_i,value_j)] = matrix.get((value_i,value_j), 0) 
                                        + np.count_nonzero(metrics[i]==metrics[j])
            if i != j:
                matrix[(value_j,value_i)] = matrix[(value_i,value_j)]
```

I want to do something like list comprehension but also want a dictionary because I update so regularly. For context I have cut this out of more elaborate code [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/270201/pooling-levels-of-categorical-variables-for-regression-trees)

-------Update--------

Awarding answer to @piRSquared for suggesting use of [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/). The gain comes from the use of this package not the use of an array instead of a dict. For comparison the following is 1.29 times slower.

```
f, u = pd.factorize(labels)
mx = f.max() + 1
matrix = np.zeros((mx, mx), np.int64)
for i in f:
    for j in f:
        if i >= j:
            matrix[i, j] = matrix[i, j] 
                           + np.count_nonzero(metrics[i] == metrics[j])
            if i != j:
                matrix[j, i] = matrix[i, j]
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix, u, u)
```

Comment: "also want a dictionary because I update so regularly" - why would that make you want a dict? It sounds like an ordinary NumPy array would be more appropriate.

Comment: *"I am trying to avoid using loops in the following code because it is slow"* Any way you slice the cake, you're going to have to use a loop, whether explicitly or under-the-hood. So I would say just get used to it

Comment: user2357112 I use a dict because it is easier to keep track of the position in the matrix.  @Jerfov2 Under the hood loops are done in compiled C++ so they are faster.

Comment: @Keith Not necessarily, it could be written in Python, C++, or [Java](http://www.jython.org/) for that matter. Also, after the first run of a python script, many (most?) implementations convert the python code into a compiled bytecode, which isn't too bad in terms of speed

Comment: @Jerfov2 So you really think there is no faster way?

Comment: @Keith Why not use a list? or a [`numpy.array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html). Numpy's arrays are fixed size and the library is written in C, so it's pretty fast. Why do you want to use an dict?

Comment: @Jerfov2 A dict allows me to update and find the correct matrix position.

Comment: @Keith Why can't you do that with a 2d array?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142667/discussion-between-keith-and-jerfov2).

Comment: Most dictionary operations work with just one key at a time, and thus require a loop such as yours.  The exceptions are `update` (from another dictionary), and the `items/values/keys` methods for fetching all components into lists.  Doing things 'without loops' is a numpy concept, and means push the loops down to compiled `numpy` code.  It does not apply to Python classes like dictionaries.

Comment: I think you should change the title to `Build a dictionary without loops`.  Since you have a `numpy` tag, your current title could be confused with a `np.matrix` object or a 2d `np.ndarray`.

Comment: @hpaulj The numpy tag was added by martineau. For the record the output format of the matrix is not important as long as I can keep track of my indexes. The current answer gives it as a dataframe which is just as good.

Comment: Using `pandas` to label columns/rows of a table is good idea.

Comment: @hpaulj "Good idea" as in faster?

Comment: Since you're repeating the same operations (which may create temporary objects), and it's all done in the processor (no I/O), that's a place to use the techniques suggested in this PyCon lecture: `How to make Python perform like C; Ron Barak;
RonPyConIsrael.comverse@xoxy.net` https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw5McUt95YdeMlNiX2VSR1lFRHM/view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still messing with this.  This is still a loop but I'm using `numba` to speed it up.  I will eventually flesh this post out with more information.  However, I wanted to give you something to work with for now.

I have other ideas to speed things up as well.

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numba import njit

@njit
def fill(f, metrics):
    mx = f.max() + 1
    matrix = np.zeros((mx, mx), np.int64)
    for i in f:
        for j in f:
            if i >= j:
                row_i = metrics[i]
                row_j = metrics[j]
                matrix[i, j] = matrix[i, j] + (row_i == row_j).sum()
            if i != j:
                matrix[j, i] = matrix[i, j]
    return matrix


def fill_from_labels(labels, metrics):
    f, u = pd.factorize(labels)
    matrix = fill(f, metrics)
    return pd.DataFrame(matrix, u, u)

df = fill_from_labels(labels, metrics)
```

Comment: Ill update after doing some tests. I thought count_nonzero was faster than sum. Is there a reason you changed this? https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8913

Comment: Also, you want to indent the second if statement is missing an indent. It does not really help with speed anyway. Updating the diagonal redundantly vs many if checks is about the same

Comment: @Keith yeah, I was using `numba` but over such a large 5M x 5M its still slow.  I have some other ideas I've been kicking around.  Don't depend on me, because I've got other stuff to do, but I find this problem interesting and I'll continue to mess with it.

Comment: Dependency on numba is not ideal since I might end up putting the project into sklearn. This is just a small piece. If you are interested there is a link to the full code in the original question.